# Launch Chrome with a very minimal Window manager

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm

So i'm setting up a box running Lubuntu and i want it to run a news website with Chrome browser on startup and with a very minimal window manager (no desktop icons,no panel...).

Is there any way to trick Lightdm or another window manager to start and run one and only app ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Window managers don't start apps.

#### ~/.xinitrc:

```
#!/bin/sh
sh -c "while true; do google-chrome; done" &
exec metacity
```

Comment: Yes i agree i had it done , but the issue is that i don't want a full lightdm environment , i just want the app to be visible (top panel,desktop hidden)

Comment: So then don't start the whole DE, just start the WM.